# NSIS - Radiobutton label not matching the one selected

Tags: button, nsis

```
!include "nsDialogs.nsh"
!include "LogicLib.nsh"

Name "Test "
OutFile Setup.exe

XPStyle on
Page Custom radioButton radioButtonClick
Page instfiles

var Group1Radio1
var Group1Radio2
var dialog
var hwnd
var label

Function radioButton
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $dialog
${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 6% "Please choose"
Pop $label
${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 12% 40% 6% "1"
Pop $Group1Radio1
${NSD_AddStyle} $Group1Radio1 ${WS_GROUP}
${NSD_OnClick} $Group1Radio1 radioButtonClick
${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 20% 40% 6% "2"
Pop $Group1Radio2
${NSD_OnClick} $Group1Radio2 radioButtonClick

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function radioButtonClick
Pop $hwnd
${If} $hwnd == $Group1Radio1
    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 40% 40% 6% "1 Selected"
    ${NSD_OnChange} $Group1Radio1 radioButton
${ElseIf} $hwnd == $Group1Radio2
    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 40% 40% 6% "2 Selected"
    ${NSD_OnChange} $Group1Radio2 radioButton

${EndIf}

FunctionEnd

Section 
SetOutPath "$DESKTOP"
SectionEnd
```

When this code runs, the name of the first button selected is corrected displayed on the label in the "Function radioButtonClick", but when you select something else after that, it doesn't update, and the button labels come out swapped.

So basically, what happens is:

click radio button 1 -> displays "1 selected"
then,
click radio button 2 -> nothing happens.
then,
click radio button 1 again -> displays "2 selected"
finally,
click radio button 2 again -> displays "1 selected"

How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make a lot of sense, you are creating a new label every time a radio button changes and you are registering a new NSD_OnChange event handler on every click and this handler tries to create another page on top of the old one, this is completely unsupported behavior!

There are many ways to code this, here are 3 examples:

```
!include "nsDialogs.nsh"
!include "LogicLib.nsh"

Page Custom radioButtonExamplePageMethod1
Page Custom radioButtonExamplePageMethod2
Page Custom radioButtonExamplePageMethod3
Page instfiles

var Group1Radio1
var Group1Radio2
var dialog
var hwnd
var label

Function radioButtonExamplePageMethod1
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $dialog
${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 6% "Please choose"
Pop $0 ; Don't care about this handle
${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 12% 40% 6% "1"
Pop $Group1Radio1
${NSD_OnClick} $Group1Radio1 radioButtonClicked_Method1
${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 20% 40% 6% "2"
Pop $Group1Radio2
${NSD_OnClick} $Group1Radio2 radioButtonClicked_Method1
${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 40% 40% 6% ""
Pop $label
; You could do 
; SendMessage $Group1Radio1 ${BM_CLICK} 0 0
; here to simulate a click for the inital radio button state
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function radioButtonClicked_Method1
Pop $hwnd
${If} $hwnd == $Group1Radio1
    ${NSD_SetText} $label "1 Selected"
${ElseIf} $hwnd == $Group1Radio2
    ${NSD_SetText} $label "2 Selected"
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd


Function radioButtonExamplePageMethod2
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $dialog
${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 6% "Please choose"
Pop $0 ; Don't care about this handle
${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 40% 40% 6% ""
Pop $label
${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 12% 40% 6% "1"
Pop $Group1Radio1
${NSD_OnClick} $Group1Radio1 radioButtonClicked_Method2_Radio1
${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 20% 40% 6% "2"
Pop $Group1Radio2
${NSD_OnClick} $Group1Radio2 radioButtonClicked_Method2_Radio2
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function radioButtonClicked_Method2_Radio1
Pop $0
${NSD_SetText} $label "1 Selected"
FunctionEnd
Function radioButtonClicked_Method2_Radio2
Pop $0
${NSD_SetText} $label "2 Selected"
FunctionEnd


Function radioButtonExamplePageMethod3
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $dialog
${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 6% "Please choose"
Pop $0 ; Don't care about this handle
${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 40% 40% 6% ""
Pop $label
${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 12% 40% 6% "1"
Pop $Group1Radio1
nsDialogs::SetUserData $Group1Radio1 "1 Selected"
${NSD_OnClick} $Group1Radio1 radioButtonClicked_Method3
${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 20% 40% 6% "2"
Pop $Group1Radio2
nsDialogs::SetUserData $Group1Radio2 "2 Selected"
${NSD_OnClick} $Group1Radio2 radioButtonClicked_Method3
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function radioButtonClicked_Method3
Pop $0
nsDialogs::GetUserData $0
Pop $1
${NSD_SetText} $label $1
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: @niamleeson: No need to say thank you, you can just mark it as the answer ;)